# How to disable <md-expansion-panel> material2 angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-template

I am facing some issues regarding official documentation of material design,
they said

**Expansion panels can be disabled using the disabled attribute. A disabled expansion panel can't be toggled by the user, but can still be manipulated using programmatically.**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="isDisabled">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-description>
    This is a summary of the content
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

But when I am trying it throwing some error-

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'md-expansion-panel'.
1. If 'md-expansion-panel' is an Angular component and it has 'disabled' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-expansion-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

            <md-expansion-panel
            [ERROR ->][disabled]="true"

               routerLink="/settings/tools"
")
```

**Any help?**

Comment: Can you update your question to show the Angular version and the Angular Material version?

Answer (score 3):

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="isDisabled">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-description>
    This is a summary of the content
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

component.ts

*Disabled set value - this.isDisabled= true;*

*Enabled set value - this.isDisabled= false;*

Answer (score 2):

'disabled' is a defined property which straight away disables user interaction on expansion panel. Directly set the property to disable any panel.

```
<mat-expansion-panel disabled>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-description>
    This is a summary of the content
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

To programmatically disable the panel please refer the below snippet which worked for me.

**Note**: < CONDITION > should evaluate to either true or false

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="<CONDITION>">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-description>
    This is a summary of the content
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

When i look at the mat-expansion-panel code (`selector: 'mat-expansion-panel'`) i see that it does have disabled as one of it's inputs (`inputs: ['disabled', 'expanded']`) but i don't see it being used...

Might i suggest a workaround: Set `pointer-events: none` on the mat-expansion-panel.

Comment: Setting disabled also greys out the content, so this is my preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

this example works

```
<mat-expansion-panel [hideToggle]="true" class="mat-elevation-z0">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>Servidores virtuales</mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expansion panels can be disabled using the disabled attribute. A disabled expansion panel can't be toggled by the user, but can still be manipulated programmatically.

"mat-expansion-panel disabled"

Add this disabled attribute inside the mat-expansion-panel tag